# Name split on passport validity

Tags: indian-citizens, passport

My name was printed incorrectly on my Indian passport (Validity: Dec 2017)and due to that I am facing lot of issues in the US. Now, I am planning to get the passport corrected.

Name as mentioned on passport currently: Given Name: YYY ZZZ Surname: [Blank]

Name as it should be: Given Name: YYY Surname: ZZZ

The question is that whether after name correction, I will be issued the passport with validity Dec 2017 or will I be issued a passport with validity 10 years from the date the name split application will be submitted.

Comment: Did you apply for a new passport and pay a new fee, or did you apply for a correction to the existing passport with no fee or a reduced fee?  Anyway, what does it matter?  More particularly, you'll know the answer when you get your new passport; do you really need to know before then?

Comment: No. But curious as I might else end up applying 6 months before expiry.

Comment: Well people often get new passports early because they've filled them up.  In my experience (none of which is with India), this results in a new 10-year passport.  So there's a fair chance this will happen for you, but the circumstances are slightly different, so maybe not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any new passport applications for Indian Passport need standard fees and are issued for 10 years from the date of passport application, no matter how many days are remaining on existing one. The existing one will be stamped Cancelled and few embassies also punch a hole, or cut one corner.

So, yes, you may apply for name split, and you will get a new 10 year valid passport.

In exceptional cases, embassies issue new passport free of cost with same validity as earlier's if it is a clerical mistake and has been brought in attention in few days of issuance.

Source: I also have same issue, using FNU as first name for US Visas (First Name Unavailable) as recommended in DS-160 form website. Inquired from Indian Embassy about split, no issues, standard fees, but then in future DS-160s,need to declare that I was also known as FNU, LastName

Comment: How would it be determined if it was a clerical mistake?

Comment: If applicant submitted papers and documents with name John Doe, and Embassy prints the name Jhon Doe. Or same thing with date of birth or any other data..

Comment: For that one would need access to the application submitted. Or would that process kick in automatically.

Comment: If by "that", you mean correction of clerical mistake, no, you need to see the information page of passport, and if Dob/name or other details have spelling mistake, you need to inform embassy asap. At same time, I have experienced different indian embassies have different rules/requirements for these not-so-comman tasks. Better to inquire with embassy in question.